# Can someone provide a bare bones Ant build script for Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, ant

Most Hibernate tutorials use Maven for handling the build, but I'm looking for a basic configuration using Ant instead. I've reviewed this some:

https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/tools/reference/en/html/ant.html

However, it seems like it covers way more in an introductory tutorial than I need. I really want to get started w/ some simple DB table to POJO mapping, and need just enough in the build script to get me started. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a project exactly along those lines.

I have just uploaded it to GitHub: [Easter's Eggs For Hibernate](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_hibernate)

It uses Postgres as the database, but the Ant file is fairly clean and you should be able to morph it to your needs. Be sure to see the ReadMe about the ordering of the Ant targets.

The intent is to clean a sandbox database and populate it with data, then reading the new data into POJOs.

Even if you don't have an account on GitHub, you can browse the source and help yourself. The build.xml, build.properties, and db.properties will be vital.

Feel free to contact me with questions.

Comment: Thanks Michael! I'm going to take a look and see if I can't get it working.